# Why is this classpath resource null?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project structured like this:

- src/main/java/test/App.java
- src/main/resources/config/message.txt

Inside App.java, I have this line:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("/config/message.txt");
```

I've tried every variation of getting the resource that I could find on Stackoverflow and Google, but it always seems to return null when I run `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=test.App`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you verified that the `message.txt` is **actually** in the built Jars?  Could you dump the output of a `jar` tool listing to an edit of your question?  I think some folks are confused about the exact structure of the Jar.  I sure am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
InputStream is = test.App.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/message.txt");
```

or simply:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/message.txt");
```

Comment: That's why I preceded the path with `/`. Otherwise `test.App.class.getResourceAsStream()` would be looking in `/test/config/message.txt` (starting from *current* class directory).

Comment: @PeterMmm:  Not it is not in the 'same directory', but the leading `/` means resolve this URL from the 'root'.  In this case, it would the the root of the class-path(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/message.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet:

```
InputStream is = App.class.
    getResourceAsStream("../../resources/config/message.txt");
```

I don't understand what you want to do with the currentThread() here.

Comment: `../../res...` - That would only be correct if `App.java` were in the package `java.test` (which I think would be 'illegal').  It should be `../res...` for a relative path.